# Servlet to MYSQL connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to write a code to search mysql database for employee ID and display relevant contents.

I have written index.jsp to input employee id and servlet code to connect to database. My problem is its not executing the statement and it throws me an output "SQL statement is not executed!"...Please help me...

```
    package mypkg;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class calandar extends HttpServlet {
/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException,IOException{
response.setContentType("text/html"); 
Connection con = null;


String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/escp?useSSL=false";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String user = "root";
String pass = "password";

String id="";
id=request.getParameter("Id");
String sqlquery="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE emp_id='"+id+"'";

try{
Class.forName(driver);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
try{
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlquery+id);
while (rs.next()) {

}
}catch (SQLException s){
System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
}
}
catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Result.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response); 
}

}
```

Comment: Because you have a `SQLException` thats the reason you got the output as `"SQL statement is not executed!"` please put `s.printStackTrace()` inside SQLException catch block and check the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right at all:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlquery+id);
```

Since you're already concatenating the ID in your query, it should just be:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlquery);
```

Also note that your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Perfect!! Good catch. Thank you so much. How do I prevent it from SQL Injection attacks?

Comment: By using prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Java/JSP. Can you please give me an example? how do I add it in my code?